# Bitbucket pipeline: bash: cap: command not found

Tags: ubuntu, rubygems, capistrano, bitbucket-pipelines, rubber

I am using rubber to deploy my Symfony project to Digital Ocean.
The project is hosted on bitbucket.

This is my Capfile.

```
require 'capistrano/setup'
require 'capistrano/deploy'
require 'capistrano/symfony'
require 'capistrano/scm/git'
install_plugin Capistrano::SCM::Git
Dir.glob('deploy/tasks/*.rake').each { |r| import r }
```

The pipeline was working well, but suddenly stopped working raising this error.

```
cap staging deploy
+ cap staging deploy
bash: cap: command not found
```

I tried reverting the commits, but it didn't help.
Tried removing capistrano from the server, but it also didn't work.

The previous steps of capistrano - `gem install bundler`, and `bundle install` works without error.

I am new to rubber and bitbucket pipeline, so maybe I missed something here?

Just got to know that the bitbucket pipeline is being executed on a docker image. Then is this the problem with the bitbucket?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay. I managed to solve this problem by changing 
`cap staging deploy` to `bundle exec cap staging deploy`.
Not sure why this could solve the problem, but anyway it works now.

Comment: did you able to find the reason?